# Python Pretty table with color output

Tags: python, python-2.7, prettytable

I am using pretty table to generate tables output.

Is it possible to generate in terms of colors. If failed it should display in red and its ok it should display in green.

Code:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
a = "ok"
b = "Failed"
t = PrettyTable(['Input', 'status'])
if a == "ok":
   t.add_row(['FAN', a])
else:
    t.add_row(['FAN', b])
print t
```

Comment: take a look at `colorama`(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of an easy way to add colour in table.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

#Color
R = "\033[0;31;40m" #RED
G = "\033[0;32;40m" # GREEN
Y = "\033[0;33;40m" # Yellow
B = "\033[0;34;40m" # Blue
N = "\033[0m" # Reset


a = "ok"
b = "Failed"
t = PrettyTable(['Input', 'status'])

#Adding Both example in table
t.add_row(['FAN', G+a+N])
t.add_row(['FAN', R+b+N])

print t
```

Comment: @SuitBoyApps - `print(t)` will fix it.

Comment: Adding Reset color fix my problem, Thnks a lot

Comment: How can we add background color as well?

I want to show red and green...but as command prompt has black background it is not readable..And if i change the background of command prompt to white, the color set by python still has black background

Comment: I had to set color="white" to make it work (in the beginnning)

Answer (score 2):

here we go

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
a = "ok"
b = "Failed"
t = PrettyTable(['Input', 'status'])
if a == "ok":
  a = "\033[1;32m%s\033[0m" %a 
  t.add_row(['FAN', a])
else:
  b = "\033[1;31m%s\033[0m" %b
  t.add_row(['FAN', b])
print t
```